# BeautifulSoup Python API Doesn't get the part I want

Tags: python-2.7, api

I have a project and i need to be take some info's on www.wikizero.com because wikipedia is not work on my country so.. I tried to make API on https://www.wikizero.com/tr/Mustafa_Kemal_Atat%C3%BCrk this site and `<div class="mw-parser-output">` under this and first `<p>` "Mustafa Kemal Atatürk[n 2] (1881[n 3] - 10 Kasım 1938), Türk mareşal ve devlet adamı. Ülkesinde monarşinin kaldırılarak cumhuriyetin kurulmasına önderlik etti ve 1923'ten 1938'e kadar cumhurbaşkanı olarak görev yaptı." this is what i want to take on web site but i can only take this.

when i write this code

```
soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"mw-parser-output"}).select("p:nth-of-type(1)")
```

its shows me this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAoiL.png)

So how i can take this blocks.? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxdJy.png)

Comment: The problem is that the `<p>` element that you're trying to extract isn't just text. It haves multiple links inside it(`<a>` tags). You'll need to extract just the text from each children of that `<div class="mw-parser-output">`.